# Apply the homology degree of maps $S^n\to S^n$ and prove the surjectivity of the following function

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to solve the following exercise

> Prove that any continuous map $f:S^n\to S^n$ such that $\|f(x)-x\|<1$ is surjective.

By property (b) of p.135 of Hatcher's book, we know that $\textrm{deg}\, (f)=0$ if $f$ is not surjective.

I would like to show that $f$ is homotopic to the identity map $id_{S^n}$. If so, its degree must be equal to $1$:
$$\textrm{deg}\, f = 1\ne 0$$
and by the property (b) commented, $f$ must be surjective.

For do so, I am stuck trying to show that $\|tf(x)+(1-t)x\|<1$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.

I feel that this step is trivial by applying some fundamental fact of the standard norm $\|\cdot\|$ but I am not able to find it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true, take $f(x)=x$, then $\|tf(x)+(1-t)x\|=1$, for every $x$ and $t$.

What you can do is the following: Define $$(x,t)\mapsto \frac{tf(x)+(1-t)x}{\|tf(x)+(1-t)x\|}$$This is a well defined map $S^n\times [0,1]\rightarrow S^n$ as long as $$tf(x)+(1-t)x\tag{*}$$ is $\neq0$, for all $(x,t)$. Assume $(x_0,t_0)$ is a zero for (*), then $$t(f(x_0)-x_0)=x_0\Rightarrow |t_0|\|f(x_0)-x_0\|=\|x_0\|=1\tag{**}$$ Using $\|f(x)-x\|<1$, for all $x\in S^n$ you can show that $|t_0|\|f(x_0)-x_0\|=1$ cannot be true.